How to use Msagl to stack vertically
Is there an existing setting in Gsagl to stack vertically?
and what I mean is I have three types  Game, Players, and Enemy. Game I would like to be central nothing else should be in that row. players should branch upwards and readjust to avoid overlaps the player nodes should never go down past the game. and the Enemy should only branch and restructure downwards and never go past the game nor into the games row in the diagram
new SugiyamaLayoutSettings(){ NodeSeperation = 30, EdgeRoutingMode = EdgeRoutingMode.StraightLine}

And is it possible to instruct the algorithm not to attach arrows at the side of the Game node?

